# How to pass a string from HTML to the Component on Angular 8 using (click) function?

Tags: angular, angular8, page-title

I have this code and it works fine:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/menuItemOne']">
    <span [innerHTML]="(mystrings$ | async)?.menuItemOne | htmlToText"></span>
</a>
```

But now I need to update the page title when the link is clicked.

I added a `setTitle` method on the component:

```ts
public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
   this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
}
```

Using `(click)` function I can update the page title and it works fine:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/menuItemOne']" (click)="setTitle('Menu Item One')">
    <span [innerHTML]="(strings$ | async)?.menuItemOneStr | htmlToText"></span>
</a>
```

But how do I do it to pass the variable `menuItemOneStr` instead of using the string `'Menu Item One'`?

I tried:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/menuItemOne']" (click)="setTitle((strings$ | async)?.menuItemOneStr | htmlToText)">
    <span [innerHTML]="(strings$ | async)?.menuItemOneStr | htmlToText"></span>
</a>
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to it on your `setTitle` method

```
public setTitle(key: string) {
    // key = menuItemOneStr, menuItemTwoStr, etc.
    this.strings$.subscribe((stringsObject: object) => {
        this.titleService.setTitle(stringsObject[key]);
    })
}
```

And in your HTML

```
<a [routerLink]="['/menuItemOne']" (click)="setTitle('menuItemOneStr')">
    <span [innerHTML]="(strings$ | async)?.menuItemOneStr | htmlToText"></span>
</a>
```

This means your subscribing to it twice, since the `async` pipe subscribes aswell. It seems like your `strings$` is `Observable<object>[]` so you can can use `ngFor` and subscribe once. This means your `setTitle` stays the same but the HTML is changed. As a note, you can use interpolation inside any tags with pipes using the `{{ variableName | somePipe }}` notation.

Updated HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let stringDetails of strings$ | async; index as i">
    <a [routerLink]="[stringDetails.link]" (click)="setTitle(stringDetails.title)">
        <span>{{stringDetails.text | htmlToText}}</span>
    </a>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your help and nice explanation.

Comment: Is there any good book or course to learn Angular that you can recommend me? Or which is the best way to learn, besides practicing? Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm still quite new to Angular, but you can use [Angular University](https://angular-university.io/course/getting-started-with-angular2) which is something that I've used. A lot of the times it's experimentation and reading the documentation from Angular.